# How to add a field into an Elastic Search document with an array of objects value?

Tags: arrays, elasticsearch, search

I am using Elastic Search 5.6 and I'd like to add a new field to an existing document. This field's value should be of type array. I was able to add a new field with an array of strings by sending a POST request with the following body

`{"script" : "ctx._source.new_field = ['string1', 'string2']"}`

to my endpoint

`http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_mapping/item_173969/_update`

and verified that the new field is there, but I need to set the value of this key to an *array of objects* instead. How can I do this? Specifically, I need my document to have:

```
"size": [
    {
        "item_size": "XL",
        "country_size": "US"
    }
]
```

Comment: please remember to mark the answer as correct if it was useful for your problem or let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there. I'm using ES 7.1 that ignores document type but the script part should work.

**Ingesting data**

```
PUT test_david/_doc/1
{
  "name": "doc1"
}
```

**Updating document**

```
POST test_david/_update/1
{
  "script": {
    "source":  "if (!ctx._source.containsKey('sizes')) ctx._source.sizes= new ArrayList(); ctx._source.sizes.add(params.data);",
    "params": {
      "data": {
        "item_size": "XL",
        "country_size": "US"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note this will validate the document has the property sizes already created and add a new size to it.

**Query**

```
POST test_david/_search
```

**Response**

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test_david",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "doc1",
          "sizes" : [
            {
              "country_size" : "US",
              "item_size" : "XL"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

About **Nested Type**

You use nested type only if you want to preserve the relationship between properties of the same children to make queries.

**Object field type let to do searches like:**

*"item_size and/or item_country on any of the size objects"*

**Nested field type searches like:**

*"item_size and/or item_country on the same size object"*

Not all nested fields needs to be of nested type. Only if you need to keep the relation between properties of the same children to do queries because nested type is more expensive and if you are only storing and displaying data it makes no sense to use this type of field.